# Upload the image file in mongodb in heroku server through flask App

Tags: python, mongodb, heroku, flask

I am trying to upload image in mongodb atlas through my flask application,when i run the same code in local host it is working fine and 2 collections are being created in mongodb "fs.files" & "fs.chunks" and able to display on my browser.I have hosted in heroku server and I am able to insert object collections but failed to upload the image. Below is the error

sock=client at=warning code=H27 desc="Client Request Interrupted" method=POST path="/upload" host=testsuheal.herokuapp.com request_id=647a0723-2a35-42f9-8a26-e60a9eb09fd7 fwd="157.45.29.249" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=3532ms status=499 bytes=0 protocol=https
2020-01-18T07:45:41.295293+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.9.158.174 - - [18/Jan/2020:07:45:41 +0000] "POST /upload HTTP/1.1" 400 192 "https://testsuheal.herokuapp.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.117 Safari/537.36"

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, render_template, request
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
from flask.json import JSONEncoder
from pymongo import MongoClient
import json,os
from bson import ObjectId
from werkzeug.utils import secure_filename
from random import random
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date
app = Flask(__name__)

APP_ROOT = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
app.config['MONGO_URI']='mongodb+srv://xxx:xxx@cluster0-52qhc.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true'
mongo = PyMongo(app)
appender=random()

@app.route('/')
def index():    
    return render_template('index.html')


@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload(): 
    photoFilename = request.files['file']   
    mongo.save_file(photoFilename.filename+str(appender),photoFilename)      
    return jsonify({'result':photoFilename.filename}) 

@app.route('/file/<filename>') 
def file(filename):    
    return mongo.send_file(filename)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Threaded option to enable multiple instances for multiple user access support
    app.run(threaded=True, port=5000)
```

Comment: Now I am able to save in the mongo db atlas but mongo.send_file is not working?